# Mounting a complete disk image rescued by ddrescue

Tags: linux, mount, ntfs, disk-image, ddrescue

I've recovered a complete NTFS disk with ddrescue in Linux. The catch is I didn't just rescue the partition (sdX#) but complete disk (sdX) with partition table.

It's really easy to mount disk partitions as loopback devices, but is there a way to mount a partition of a complete disk image in the same way? I can write the image to another disk but I feel it shouldn't be necessary.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you imaged the whole drive you can use offset option with mount command. mmls (from The [Sleuth Kit](http://sleuthkit.org/sleuthkit/)) can show partitions within an image

```
$ mmls image -b
DOS Partition Table
Offset Sector: 0
Units are in 512-byte sectors

     Slot    Start        End          Length       Size    Description
00:  -----   0000000000   0000000000   0000000001   0512B   Primary Table (#0)
01:  -----   0000000001   0000000031   0000000031   0015K   Unallocated
02:  00:01   0000000032   0001646591   0001646560   0803M   DOS FAT16 (0x06)
03:  00:00   0001646592   0002013183   0000366592   0179M   DOS FAT16 (0x06)
```

Mount the DOS partition starting at block 32:

```
sudo mount -o loop,offset=16384 image mnt
```

(32 multiplied by 512 byte blocks = 16384)

For mounting a typical NTFS partition created by Windows use:

```
sudo mount -t ntfs -o r,force,loop,offset=32256 image mnt
```

(63 multiplied by 512 byte blocks = 32256)

Comment: Should that really be `-o r,...` and not, say, `-o ro,...`?

Comment: In 2022 that first call to `mmls` fails because option `-b` requires a block size. To show the table, just use `mmls image-file`.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution is to use losetup to map the image to a block device, then kpartx to scan the loopback device and create block devices for each partition, and then mount those. Something like (untested)

```
losetup /device/loop0 /path/to/file.img
kpartx /dev/loop0
mount /device/mapper/loop0p1 /mntpath
```

Comment: For anyone trying to use this method at 2022, `kpartx` should be used as `kpartx -a /dev/loop0`.